# Titanium - remote image can't display as background in Imageview

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have created an application in the alloy framework (Titanium). I get the image name and url for fetch image from the webserver. I set this fetched image as background of Imageview. It displays fine in an IPhone device and simulator but it does not display in an Android device and emulator. I used the code below:

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();  

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("UPDATE PROFILE: "+this.responseText);

        var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        if(result['success'] == 1) {
            var data = result['data'];

            $.imgNotification.image = Alloy.Globals.uploadImageURL+result['data']['picture'];
            $.imgProfilePic.image = Alloy.Globals.uploadImageURL+result['data']['picture'];
            $.imgProfilePic3.image = Alloy.Globals.uploadImageURL+result['data']['picture'];
        }

    };

    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        Titanium.API.info('userLogin error: ' + e.error);
        alert('Check your network connection');
    }; 

    xhr.open('POST', Alloy.Globals.webserviceURL);
    xhr.send({method : 'getMyDetails', userid: userID});
```

A remote image is not display in android device.

Comment: Anyone can help me or suggest me?

Comment: First, why you did declare variable `data` and used anyway `result['data']['picture']`? Every image has the same url so you can do something like `var imageURL = Alloy.Globals.uploadImageURL + result['data']['picture'];`. Now back to the problem... Can you show me how does look the URL?

Comment: my above code working fine in iPhone device but not in android device...means image display properly in iPhone device but not in android device.

Comment: I understand. Can you try `console.log(Alloy.Globals.uploadImageURL+result['data']['picture']);` and show me the url?

Comment: yes..I tried alot and I used `Alloy.Globals.uploadImageURL = 'http://www.xyz.net/app/usersData/images/';` and also check this url in web browser.

Comment: @0101 , Have you any solution for this minor but major problem?

Comment: Well, if you will not show me the url I can't give you any solution. I have to see output from `console.log($.imgNotification.image);`

Comment: @0101, url is live i can't give you.There is no any option for display image directly from remote server, where as iPhone has possible.Have you any other solution?

Comment: The problem is that it does work (I have tried it) ,so problem must be somewhere in your code. If you can't provide any more code / url I can't help you. No body can help you. If you want to solve your problem post here View & Style & URL (You can delete the URL later...)